# Relations with view oracle forms

Tags: forms, oracle, database-relations

I have two blocks on my form. The firs block: **"vista_clientes"**, and the second **"pedidos"**. The first is based on a **view**, and the second on a **table**.

I go to **relations** on my first block, and press "*create*", then, I choose "*pedidos*" how *detail block*. I choose the common field (primary key) and create the relations.

I have some errors when I go to execute this, **depends of the delete way that I choose**, I have three options, isolated, cascade and no-isolated, I can open the fmx file with cascade or no-iolated, when I set the isolated, I can open the fmx but the execute query from "vista_clientes" doesn't work.

The error is that my vista clientes Alias dont have a proper ID and the method REF from the automatically created with the relation give this error.

**Relation Screen's Options**:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/5/capturazvg.jpg/

**Error on Cascade (PRE-DELETE TRIGGER)**:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/capturahi.jpg/

**Error on Isolated**: 
This allows open the canvas, but not works - Execute Query ERROR 40505 or If I use DISPLAY_ERROR I see this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/17/capturack.jpg/

**Error on Non-Isolated**:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/capturaoej.jpg/

I really need help with this. Thanks a lot! :)

PD: Sorry my english! I can add more details or screenshots if It will help to solve this problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VISTA_CLIENTES ( CLIENTE_NO, 
CLIENTE_NIF, NOMBRE, DIRECCION, LOCALIDAD, 
PROVINCIA, EMP_NO, APELLIDO, DEPT_NO, 
DNOMBRE ) AS SELECT clientes.cliente_no, clientes.cliente_nif, clientes.nombre,
       clientes.direccion, clientes.localidad, clientes.provincia,
       emple.emp_no, emple.apellido, depart.dept_no, depart.dnombre
  FROM clientes, emple, depart
 WHERE (    (emple.emp_no = clientes.vendedor_no)
        AND (depart.dept_no = emple.dept_no)
       )
```

---

It looks about oracle forms bug. I set the relation writing and works, If I choose the field on the selectbox, the relation not works.

Comment: Is the view updatable?

Comment: I think so. (Update first post)

Comment: Check this link to see. Since you're getting values from multiple tables in the view, I suspect it's not. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm

Comment: looks about oracle forms bug. I set the relation writing and works, If I choose the field on the selectbox, the relation not works. Thanks a lot for the help. :)